# In an azure Logic app workflow step that inserts into DocumentDB, how can I "toString" a number

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I'm getting an error saying that id is a number when triggering a "create document" in DocumentDb step in my logic app.  How can I `toString` the `id` number in the insert step?

```
  "actions": {
            "Create_or_update_document": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "body": "@triggerBody()",
                        "createdAt": "@triggerBody()?['created_at']",
                        "description": "@triggerBody()?['description_text']",
                        "dueBy": "@triggerBody()?['due_by']",
                        "priority": "@triggerBody()?['priority']",
                        "requesterId": "@triggerBody()?['requester_id']",
                        "source": "@triggerBody()?['source']",
                        "status": "@triggerBody()?['status']",
                        "id": "@triggerBody()?['id']",
                        "type": "@triggerBody()?['type']",
                        "updatedAt": "@triggerBody()?['updated_at']"
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language) (look under`Conversion functions`):

```
"@string(triggerBody()?['id'])"
```